# Bash script with user interaction if more than one matches found

Tags: bash

I have bash script (user_remove.sh) to remove users from the file name address_book.
user_remove.sh perform below actions:

1) get the single input via command like argument and assign to variable know as a name. (name="$1")

2) grep the name from the address_book and re-direct the output wc command and store the result in variable matches.

3) Test the condition matches is greater then one, if yes (zero) echo message will print, "More than one match; Please select one to remove" and interact with user to ask confirmation (y/n) y to remove the matched user.

```
#!/bin/bash

name="$1"

matches=$(grep "$name" address_book | wc -l)


if [ "$matches" -gt 1 ]
then
    echo "More than one match; Please select one to remove"
    echo "$name Remove (y/n)?"
    read answer

    if [ "$answer" = y ]
    then
             grep -v "$name" address_book > my_tmp/address_book
             mv my_tmp/address_book address_book

    elif [ "$answer" = n ]
    then
            exit 0
    else
            echo "I could not find $name in address_book"

    fi
fi
```

address_book file contain two line of data :

```
test abc
test xyz
```

Sample Runs:

```
$./user_remove.sh test
More than one match; Please select one to remove
test Remove (y/n)?y
```

Here is my question: i want output like this:

```
More than one match; Please select one to remove
test abc Remove (y/n)?y
test xyz Remove (y/n)?n
```

Could you please help me on this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minor adjustment to what you have.  Key is to store the matches in an array before looping through them.

```
#!/bin/bash

name="$1"

# Find all matches
matches=()
while read -r match
do
    matches+=("$match")
done < <(grep "$name" address_book)

# Loop through matches if more than one found
if [ "${#matches[@]}" -gt 1 ]
then
    for match in "${matches[@]}"
    do
        echo "More than one match; Please select one to remove"
        echo "$match Remove (y/n)?"
        read answer

        if [ "$answer" = y ]
        then
             grep -v "$match" address_book > my_tmp/address_book
             mv my_tmp/address_book address_book

        elif [ "$answer" = n ]
        then
             exit 0
        else
             echo "I could not find $name in address_book"
        fi
    done
fi
```

But what you probably really want is this...

```
#!/bin/bash

name="$1"

matches=()
while read -r match
do
    matches+=("$match")
done < <(grep "$name" address_book)

if [ "${#matches[@]}" -gt 1 ]
then
    echo "More than one match; Please select one to remove"
    for match in "${matches[@]}"
    do
        echo "$match Remove (y/n)?"
        read answer

        if [ "$answer" = y ]
        then
            grep -v "$match" address_book > address_book2
            mv my_tmp/address_book address_book
        fi
    done
elif [ "${#matches[@]}" -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "I found one occurence of $name in address_book"
else
    echo "I could not find $name in address_book"
fi
```

Comment: Hi Flu, Thanks lot of your answer. Your idea is working fine for me. Here i have one question what is the meaning  of matches+=("$match") this part ? could you please tell me ?

Comment: Hi @user6420577, glad it's working.  This appends the entire matched (via grep) line to an array called matches.  It's quoted to preserve the entire line as opposed to each word of every line.

Comment: Also @user6420577, if you feel this is the correct answer, would you kindly check it off as such.  Thank you!

Comment: And how to test the condition if match is greater than 1 else match is equal to 1.

Comment: @user6420577, sorry, I missed that detail.  Added.